Setting UNNotificationCenterDelegate while using firebase_messaging plugin
I am working on a Flutter app. I am using Firebase Messaging to handle push notifications. This is all working fine. However, there is no support for notification action buttons on iOS. So, I thought I'd define these myself in the AppDelegate and then communicate with the Flutter side using a MethodChannel. This also works but what I'm running into is:
In order to handle the action response of a button, I have defined this function in my AppDelegate:
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center 
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler

and I'm setting the delegate in didFinishLauncingWithOptions:
[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;

But when I do this, the didReceiveNotificationResponse of FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin is not called any more. I would like this plugin to also handle the response, so it can handle the response when just the notification itself is clicked.
Looking at the code of the didReceiveNotificationResponse method of FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin it should forward calls to the "original" delegate. However, if I don't set the AppDelegate as the delegate, so the method in the plugin gets called, the original delegate is not AppDelegate and so the call does not get forwarded.
// Forward on to any other delegates.
if (_originalNotificationCenterDelegate != nil &&
  _originalNotificationCenterDelegateRespondsTo.didReceiveNotificationResponse) {
[_originalNotificationCenterDelegate userNotificationCenter:center
                             didReceiveNotificationResponse:response
                                      withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
} else {
    completionHandler();
}

Any ideas on how to approach this? I have tried calling [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self]; after setting AppDelegate as the delegate but no dice. What I would like to have happen is that the firebase plugin does its setup after the setting of AppDelegate as the delegate, so it replaces that delegate and forwards the call, instead of what is happening now, where it seems me setting AppDelegate as the delegate overrides the firebase plugin being the delegate.
Or if there are better ways to approach this I'm all ears of course.

What I've done now is created a plugin, defined the didReceiveNotificationReponse there as well as the notification actions. In this plugin I have registered for events from the UNNotificationCenter via the FlutterPluginRegistrar:
[registrar addApplicationDelegate:instance];

It is only possible to receive UNNotificationCenter events via de plugin registrar if the FlutterAppLifeCycleProvider is set as the UNNotificationCenterDelegate (e.g. AppDelegate is set as the UNNotificationCenterDelegate).
